# Remove part of Powershell Result within Invoke Command

Tags: regex, powershell, invoke-command

I have the following line:

```
"OSType" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.Description -like "W*" -and $_.licensestatus -eq 1 ) } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description} `
```

That produces:  OSType   : Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_SLP channel

I am doing this in a ForEach statement and it works fine but I want the output to be just:  OSType:  OEM_SLP

I can do this to break it apart but then it takes the value from the last computer and puts it in for every entry:

```
$OSType = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.Description -like "W*" -and $_.licensestatus -eq 1 ) } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description} `

        $OS1 = $OSType.Split(',')[1] 

        $OS2 = $OS1.Split(' ')[1]

        "OSType" = $OS2
```

It fails if I try to use the Invoke command on the bottom 3 lines.  Any Ideas?

Here is my entire script:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Computers.txt"

$Results = @()

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{

        "Computer" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty SystemName } `

        "CPU1" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*1*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*0*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Name } `

        "Cores1" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*1*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*0*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores } `

        "LogProc1" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*1*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*0*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors } 

        "CPU2" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*2*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*#1*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Name } `

        "Cores2" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*2*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*#1*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores } `

        "LogProc2" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*2*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*#1*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors } `

        "OS" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption } `

        #"OSType" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.Description -like "W*" -and $_.licensestatus -eq 1 ) } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description} `

        $OSType = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.Description -like "W*" -and $_.licensestatus -eq 1 ) } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description} `

        $OS1 = $OSType.Split(',')[1] 

        $OS2 = $OS1.Split(' ')[1]

        "OSType" = $OS2

        "SP" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServicePackMajorVersion } `

        "OSArch" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OSArchitecture } `

        "Office" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object -FilterScript { (($_.Publisher -like "Microsoft*") -and ($_.DisplayName -like "*Office 64*")) } | Select-Object -first 1 -ExpandProperty DisplayName }

        "FullSQL" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {If (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names") { Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object -FilterScript { (($_.Publisher -like "Microsoft*") -and ($_.DisplayName -like "Microsoft SQL Server*(*-bit)")) } | Select-Object -first 1 -ExpandProperty DisplayName }}

    }
}

$Results | Select-Object Computer, CPU1, Cores1, LogProc1, CPU2, Cores2, LogProc2, OS, OSType, SP, OSArch, Office, FullSQL | Sort-Object Computer
```

Comment: well, it would be easier to use `.split(' ')[-2]` instead of that construct you are using. `$OS1 = $OSType.Split(',')[1] 

        $OS2 = $OS1.Split(' ')[1]

        "OSType" = $OS2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$OSType = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
     Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct | 
        Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.Description -like "W*" -and $_.licensestatus -eq 1 ) } | 
        select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description
     }) -replace '.*,\s?(\S+).*', '$1'
```

However, I would highly recommend you to invoke `Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor` only **once** before you creating the object. Just store the result in a variable and access / filter it.

---

**Edit:** 
To get rid of all your `Get-WmiObject` calls, you could do something like this:

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $win32processor =  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor  }

    $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Computer" = $win32processor | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty SystemName
        "CPU1" = $win32processor | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*1*") -or ($_.SocketDesignation -like "*0*") } | select-object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Name
    #........
```

Comment: Trying it now.  Will let you know.

Comment: @4c74356b41 It depends. If you are familiar with regex, its not harder to read then a split with a negative index. Also, I prefer regex here since you can make it more reliable if you have to.

Comment: Agreed on reliability, but in this particular case `split` looks cleaner :) just my opinion.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Probably yes. However, I catched myself never using split, indexof, etc. since I learned regex - its like when you have a hammer, your problems look like nails ;-). But there are indeed situations where regex is a overkill...

Comment: So this does work very well, I appreciate it, both responses.  Now how do you invoke the Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor when you have to have different filters applied and different output names?

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example. If you stuck on this, please start a new question.

Comment: @Martin Brandi, Wow, so much faster doing it that way, thank you so much!!